# Phoenix Framework: Is inputs_for available for the has_many associations?

Tags: phoenix-framework

Using the Phoenix Framework, I want to implement the nested form like the *fields_for* of the RoR.
Today I tried to implement it with *inputs_for*, but I got the error.

Referring the official document of Phoenix Framework, I could found the sample with *inputs_for*. It describes only the sample with the *embed_one* association. And I met the error with the *has_many* association.

How can I implement the nested form for the *has_many* association correctly?

The schemata are as below:

```
defmodule AnApp.User do
    use PhoenixBlog.Web, :model

    schema "users" do
        field :handle, :string
        field :password_digest, :string

        has_many  :emails
    end
end

defmodule AnApp.Email do
    use PhoenixBlog.Web, :model

    schema "emails" do
        field :address, :string
    end
end
```

And I implemented the form.html.eex as below:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
    <%= inputs_for f, :emails, fn ef -> %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This cause the error **Argument Error: unknown field :emails**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, right now it supports only embeds. We are working on supporting associations next. The error messages in the newly released Phoenix.Ecto should also be clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer.

I additionally want to know whether or not *inputs_for* will support the non-Ecto structs. Non-Ecto struct support will help to implement the forms based on transient items, for instance, search forms.

Comment: @elcondor, can you do another question for that? Specifically on how to do search forms. The [answer is here](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html) (With connection data section) but I think it would help tons of people if we had a direct question. :)

Comment: A heads up that with Phoenix Ecto 1.0, associations are now supported in inputs_for.

Comment: Thank you for your notice. I'll try it soon!